How to optimize equations involving trigonometric functions using Ceres?
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
#include<ceres/ceres.h>
#include<ceres/rotation.h>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#define M_PI 3.141592653
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
// 定义一个辅助函数来创建旋转矩阵


class ProjectError
{
public:
    ProjectError(const Eigen::Vector3d obj_pt, const Eigen::Vector2d img_pixel) : m_obj_pt(obj_pt), m_img_pixel(img_pixel) {}
    template <typename T>
    bool operator()(const T* const input, T* residuals) const
    {
        // 计算残差
        residuals[0] = std::cos(input[0]);

        return true;
    }

    // 生成误差函数
    static ceres::CostFunction* Create(Eigen::Vector3d obj_pt, Eigen::Vector2d img_pixel)
    {      
        return (new ceres::AutoDiffCostFunction<ProjectError, 2, 15>(new ProjectError(obj_pt, img_pixel)));
    }

    EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW

private:
    const Eigen::Vector3d m_obj_pt;
    const Eigen::Vector2d m_img_pixel;

};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //15个变量 前9个是rtk的  后6个是外参
    
}


like this  but it have error  error C2665: “cos”: 3 个重载中没有一个可以转换所有参数类型
I have tried many methods, but none of them have worked.This short example represents my problem.   钱钱钱钱钱钱钱钱钱钱钱钱钱钱钱钱钱钱钱

Please change your systems regional settings to English, to get an English error message that you can copy-paste into your question. Also make sure you copy-paste the full and complete build-log, and add comments in the code on the lines you get the errors.
